# CI pipeline - gradle steps inside container which fails sometimes when it tries to download dependencies from other server (artifactory servers)

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

I have to run a Gradle assemble inside a container and that downloads maven dependencies from other local server which is an Artifactory server configured in the same network. Sometime Gradle can successfully download the dependencies; but sometimes it times out and fails. This happens like once in few runs.

Here is the small summary of the the setup

A Jenkins with the slave , I have a pipeline code that will spin a docker container inside slave and that container will run gradle assemble

Few more details

Jenkins - 2.107.2
Gradle version - 4.10
Container - ubuntu:18.04

Docker file looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG SSH_KEY
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ENV TERM=linux
ENV TZ=Europe/Stockholm
ENV MZ_HOME=/opt/mz
ENV PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MZ_HOME/bin:$PATH
<< SOME STEPS TO SETUP ENVIRONMENT>>

USER jenkins

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Jenkins pipline with the small shell script that will be running inside the container.

Here is the code in the pipeline

```
    stage('assemble') {
  agent{
    docker{
      alwaysPull true
      image ‘dtr.registry.com/project/jdk-build-project:latest'
      reuseNode true
    }
  }
  steps{
    dir(‘project’){
      sh 'bash -ex env.sh -command "./gradlew assemble --continue --stacktrace"'
    }
  }    
}
```

And the error log is random.. but a sample is this.. and I have no clue why this is not failing all the time and it fails once is few successful builds

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':system_insight'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration         ':system_insight:classpath'.
> Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:20.0)
> Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar'.
     > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar'.
        > Read timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide logs, attempted fixes, and any other information like Jenkins version, list of plugins, HTTP req/res content, HTTP response code from Artifactory, and any other related debug information.

Comment: From what I can tell it looks like the container does not have network access to https://repo.maven.apache.org/ . Are you able to SSH into the Jenkins node and run the pipeline steps manually? shell into the container (while on the build node) and attempt to curl or wget the Maven resource.

Comment: Sure thing!, I did tried to do that multiple times.. i have a had a wget in loop multiple time that works fine,, again this issues is seems to be intermittent not always.. fails..

Comment: "...intermittent not always..." sounds like either network failure or remote resource going away for some reason. Do you have logs from the network traffic?